# GitHub actions for testing Haskell package?

Tags: haskell, github-actions

Recently I was lured from Travis CI to GitHub actions for my Julia project by the ease of configuration and out-of-the box success with *all* of the example Actions I found, and thought I'd try the same with my [Haskell project](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.travis.yml). But *none* of the example Haskell Actions I found function at all, most failing with security or `gcc` compiler flag errors, even for exactly the same commands that work in Travis CI.

Are there examples of *functioning* Haskell GitHub Actions? I suspect I'm just not looking in the right place for the latest working examples.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, after a lot of trial and error, I ended up with [roughly this](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.github/workflows/test.yml), which works perfectly:

```yaml
name: Tests

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: [hackage, develop]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ghc: ['8.8.3', '8.10.5']
        cabal: ['2.4.1.0', '3.0.0.0']
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        resolver: [lts-3.22 , lts-17, lts-18, lts]
        exclude:
          # GHC 8.8+ only works with cabal v3+
          - ghc: 8.8.3
            cabal: 2.4.1.0
    name: ${{ matrix.resolver }} (${{ matrix.ghc }}/${{ matrix.cabal }})
    steps:

      - name: Check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Haskell
        uses: haskell/actions/setup@v1
        with:
          ghc-version: ${{ matrix.ghc }}
          cabal-version: ${{ matrix.cabal }}
          enable-stack: true

      - name: Versions
        run: |
          stack --version
          cabal --version
          ghc --version

      - name: Initalize stack for LTS
        run: |
          stack update
          stack init --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} --force

      - name: Build package dependencies
        run: |
          stack --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} build --no-run-tests --no-run-benchmarks --only-dependencies

      - name: Build package
        run: |
          stack --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} build --no-run-tests --no-run-benchmarks

      - name: Build testing dependencies
        run: |
          stack --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} build --no-run-tests --no-run-benchmarks --test --bench

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          stack --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} build --test --no-run-benchmarks

      - name: Package list
        run: |
          stack --resolver ${{ matrix.resolver }} exec ghc-pkg list || true
```

(Though I'm not sure the build steps are in quite the right order [for what I intend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68400835/656912), and have some questions about [where caching should go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68412805/656912).)