# Where should caching occur in a GitHub Action?

Tags: caching, github-actions, haskell-stack

What is the correct placement of [caching in a GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows)? Specifically is in correct to place it before or after running setup of tools using another Action?

For example if I'm [using something](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.github/workflows/test.yml) like `haskell/actions/setup` should my use of `actions/cache` precede or follow that? Put another way: if `setup` subsequently installs updated components on a future run of my Action, will the corresponding parts of the cache be invalidated?

Comment: The [example workflow](https://github.com/actions/cache#example-workflow) shows that it is placed before your action.

Comment: @DannyB That example doesn’t show where caching goes wrt tools installation. Especially tools installation using another action. That’s the question.

Comment: The caching action is just copying a folder to a permanent place, based on the key. If you are using another action that creates/consumes cache, the cache action needs to either be integrated with it (like the [ruby setup action is doing](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#single-job)), or configured as explained in the linked example (or my answer).

Comment: @DannyB So in the case of something like `haskell/actions/setup` which is installing tools, caching goes after?

Comment: No, caching will always go before - the "after" part is happening automatically. Ideally, the authors of the haskell action can implement caching in their action, but if they don't, then all you need to do is understand which folder(s) you want to cache, and set up that caching action with that folder and appropriate key (probably one that uses the hashing function I mentioned on the haskell file that represents the list of dependencies).

Comment: I have added the workflow YAML file that I used to generate the screenshots below, to make it more clear that the "after" part was added automatically by GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

The cache action should be placed **before** any step that consumes or creates that cache. This step is responsible for:

1. defining cache parameters.
2. restoring the cache, if it was cached in the past.

GitHub Actions will then run a "Post *" step after all the steps, which will store the cache for future calls.

See the example workflow from the [documentation](https://github.com/actions/cache#example-workflow).

For example, consider this sample workflow:

```yaml
name: Caching Test

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Enable Cache
      id: cache-action
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: cache-folder
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-cache-key

    - name: Use or generate the cache
      if: steps.cache-action.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: mkdir cache-folder && touch cache-folder/hello

    - name: Verify we have our cached file
      run: ls cache-folder
```

This is how it looks on the first run:
[image]

And this is how it looks on the second run:
[image]

GitHub will not invalidate the cache. Instead, it is the responsibility of the developer to ensure that the cache key is unique to the content it represents.

On common way to do this, is to set the cache key so that it contains a hash of a file that lives in the repository, so that changes to this file, will yield a different cache key. A good example for such a behavior, is when you have lock files that list all your repository's dependencies (`requirements.txt` for pyrhon, `Gemfile.lock` for ruby, etc).

This is achieved by a syntax similar to this:

```yaml
key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/lockfiles') }}
```

as described in the [Creating a cache key](https://github.com/actions/cache#creating-a-cache-key) section of the documentation.